# Angular how to build the requestBody in http calls?

Tags: angular, http, web-services, post

Imagine i have multiple input fields:

> projectName, customerName, employeeName

The user can fetch data from an API depending on which values he input on this fields.
If he enters some values, the RequestBody will maybe look like this:

```
{
    "projectName": "Opel Travel",
    "customerName": "",
    "employeeName": "",
}
```

How should i build the requestBody when the user types nothing into the fields, to get all data without filtering for values?

variant1:

```
{
    "projectName": "",
    "customerName": "",
    "employeeName": "",
}
```

The API dont return any data, so i guess this approach is wrong.

variant2:

```
{

}
```

with this approach i get all data.

What is best practice to build the request body? The Goal is, to get all data if user inputs nothing otherwise filter for his inputs.

Comment: so you have to build a mapper that filter a empty property and remove them from the object that the api doesn't get the empty property. In the Backend you have to allow optional values to not getting a error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it also depends upon how you handled null cases while inserting the data.  And filtering through parameters has nothing much to do on the front-end side.
If any parameter (input field) is "" in the request, you should manage to convert the empty string to null or 0 depending on how you sent the data while inserting into the databases.

Let suppose you sent this object to save in the databases

```
{
    "projectName": "Opel Travel",
    "customerName": "",
    "employeeName": "",
}
```

**"customerName"** and **"employeeName"** should be saved as null as they contain no value.